# Is it possible to hide the checkbox column when enabling multiSelect?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Is it possible to hide the checkbox column on the left when enabling multiSelect? I would just like to enable the multiSelect via Ctrl, I don't need the checkboxes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Set the enableRowHeaderSelection: false in your grid options.

This will hide the check boxes for you.